# finding and element in xamarin forms listview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have xamarin.forms.listview control and I have some elements in it. This listview will be populated dynamically. Now on a particular
 condition, I need to hide one element inside the listview, how can I
 find it and hide it?

```
<ListView x:Name="lstBids" Margin="0" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame Margin="0,0,0,5" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource Medium}" Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" x:Name="lblComments" Text="{Binding Comments}"></Label>
                                <Frame x:Name="frmHire" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource base}" Padding="10,5" CornerRadius="5" HasShadow="False">
                                    <Label Text="Hire" Style="{StaticResource MediumWhite}"></Label>
                                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Hire_Clicked"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Frame>
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource SmallGray}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  Margin="0,0,10,0"  x:Name="lblDate" Text="{Binding UpdatedDate, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt}'}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

`frmHire` is the frame I need to hide in all the listview items on a particular condition, how can I achieve it? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply bind the `IsVisible` property on your `frmHire` to the condition on the item of the `ItemsSource`.

The parent view model hosting the `ObservableCollection` or `List` will just have to go through the items and set the condition accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the name of frame and get it in code behind . As **Roubachof** said.You can use data-binding to binding the value of `IsVisible`.And change it in ViewModel .

> in xaml

```
<Frame IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"  Padding="10,5" CornerRadius="5" HasShadow="False">
   //...

</Frame>
```

> in your model

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Comments { get; set; }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



  protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  {
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  private bool isvisible;
  public bool IsVisible
  {
    get
    {
       return isvisible;
    }
    set
    {
      if (isvisible != value)
      {
         isvisible = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged();
      }
     }
 }

        //...other property
}
```

And you can set the value of it.For example ,if you want to set all frame `isVisible` as `false`

```
foreach(var model in MyItems)
{
  model.IsVisible = false;
}
```

**MyItems** is the `ItemsSource` of listview . Don't forget init the property when you init the ItemsSource .Otherwise the value of `IsVisible` is `false` in default.